# iphone sdk - why is the video returned not full res?

Tags: iphone, video

im developing an app for the iphone and im able to get a video using a UIImagePickerController
the problem is that the video thats returned by the UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is not full resoultion -- its only 480 x 360 as opposed to 640 x 480 like the videos that sync to my itunes.

-please someone tell me this is not a limitation of the current sdk?
- how can i work around it and is there a way to set the uiimage picker so its taking full res video?

Comment: The UIImagePickerControllerDelegate only returns an NSURL, which points to the movie. How are you further processing that movie? Are you showing it in an MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: i am uploading the raw file to a server through http where i inspect the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and apple only uses 480x320 in their you-tube uploads from the iphone.
so it doesn't seem possible under the possible SDK. Thats not to say the iphone isnt capable of it, it can take 640x480 resolution video. Looks like we need to wait for the next update of the SDK and see if they have allowed this.

I was surprised to see that no one else is complaining of this because we all want maximum video resolution, especially with HSDPA + faster upload speeds and HD becoming the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The iphone only has a resolution of [480-by-320-pixels](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html), so UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL being an iphone only library does not return videos at a higher resolution than the phone is capable of displaying. 
Likely this is to prevent people from accidentally using more bandwidth/cpu/battery power than they would actually need.

Comment: this doesn't really make sense given the fact that videos taken on the iphone and synced to itunes are 640x480. Yes the screen is 480x320 but the camera resolution is independent of this. The iphone takes video natively at 640x480 not 480x320 but it seems as soon as you use the api it resizes it to 480x320. this is super disappointing for anyone trying to create decent video applications. Also to clarify the UIImagePicker  *does* return images bigger than 480x320 if you request , it just seems it wont do so with the video :( thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you decompile the itunes code and see what classes it calls. I've never decompiled objective c, but Java in many cases decompiles into almost readable source code. At the very least you could see the libraries methods they are calling.

Comment: Yes, I think i could get access to an undocumented api if i sniffed round, but then my app would be rejected from the app store for the same reasons.